# When i tap a TextField, navigator push to the current page again

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, navigator

I have an app with variable form fields (textFields, selects, etc, that i read from a json and transform on widgets). The current screen was initially pushed from a Home screen. When i tap a text field and the keyboard appears, the navigator automatically push again (4 times!) to the current screen. Then, i have to press the back button 4 times to recover the original current screen and, again, the navigator push 4 more times to the same screen.

Here is the textfield code part

```
class SingleTextFormFieldWidget extends TextFormFieldWidget {
  final UniqueLineText uniqueLineText;
  late TextInputType keyboardType;
  late bool obscureText;
  late BuildContext _context;

  SingleTextFormFieldWidget({
    Key? key, 
    required this.uniqueLineText,
    required int indexInPage,
    bool? avaible
  }): super(
    key: utils.getFormFieldKey('single_text', uniqueLineText.name), 
    indexInPage: indexInPage, 
    avaible: avaible ?? true
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    _defineTextFieldParams();
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: AppDimens.getWidthByScreen(0.02, context)
      ),
      child: VariableVerticalTitledFormFieldContainer(
        title: uniqueLineText.label,
        child: (
          avaible?
            TextFormField(
              enabled: avaible,
              initialValue: uniqueLineText.uniqueValue??uniqueLineText.placeholder,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                helperText: uniqueLineText.description??'',
                helperStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: AppDimens.getNormalTextSize(context)
                ),
                isDense: true,
                border: _createInputBorder(context),
                enabledBorder: _createInputBorder(context)
              ),
              onChanged: onChanged,
            ): DisabledTextField(
              text: uniqueLineText.uniqueValue ?? ''
            )
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }

  InputBorder _createInputBorder(BuildContext context){
    return OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppDimens.getWidthByScreen(0.12, context)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.525),
        width: 2.5
      )
    );
  }

  void _defineTextFieldParams(){
    obscureText = false;
    _defineKeyboardTypeByTextSubType();
  }

  void _defineKeyboardTypeByTextSubType(){
    if(uniqueLineText.subType == TextSubType.TEXT){
      _defineKeyboardTypeAsText();
    }else if(uniqueLineText.subType == TextSubType.EMAIL){
      _defineEmailSubtypeConfig();
    }else if(uniqueLineText.subType == TextSubType.PASSWORD){
      _definePasswordSubtypeConfig();   
    }else if(uniqueLineText.subType == TextSubType.TEL){
      _defineTelSubtypeConfig();
    }else if(uniqueLineText.subType == TextSubType.COLOR){
      _defineKeyboardTypeAsText();   
    }
  }

  void _defineKeyboardTypeAsText(){
    keyboardType = TextInputType.text;
  }

  void _defineEmailSubtypeConfig(){
    keyboardType = TextInputType.emailAddress;
  }

  void _definePasswordSubtypeConfig(){
    _defineKeyboardTypeAsText();
    obscureText = true;
  }

  void _defineTelSubtypeConfig(){
    keyboardType = TextInputType.phone;
  }

  void onChanged(String newValue){
    uniqueLineText.uniqueValue = newValue;
    BlocProvider.of<FormulariosBloc>(_context).add(UpdateFormularioCampo());
  }
}
```

Here is the fraction where the form fields are

```
class FormfieldsFraction extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool formFieldsAreEnabled;
  late OnShowingFormularioDetail onFormularioDetailState;
  FormfieldsFraction({
    super.key, 
    required this.formFieldsAreEnabled
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    onFormularioDetailState = BlocProvider.of<FormulariosBloc>(context).state as OnShowingFormularioDetail;
    return (
      (onFormularioDetailState.nPages > 0)?
        _createFormFieldsWithIndex(context):
        Container()
    );
  }

  Widget _createFormFieldsWithIndex(BuildContext context){
    List<CustomFormField> formFIeldsFromPage = onFormularioDetailState.formFieldsFromPage;
    final List<Widget> children = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < formFIeldsFromPage.length; i++){
      children.add(FormFieldWidgetFactory.createFormFieldWidget(formFIeldsFromPage[i], i, formFieldsAreEnabled));
      children.add(SizedBox(
        height: AppDimens.getHeightByScreen(0.025, context)
      ));
    }
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: children,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The FormFieldWidgetFactory.createFormFieldWidget creates the widget depending on the object (single text, text area, select, check box, etc). The problem ocurs when the widget is a TextField and i tap it.

This is its parent widget code

```
class FormularioView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Formulario formulario;
  final bool isVisitFormulario;
  const FormularioView({
    required this.formulario,
    required this.isVisitFormulario,
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormularioViewState createState() => _FormularioViewState();
}

class _FormularioViewState extends State<FormularioView> {
  late ScrollController scrollController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final onFormDetailState = (BlocProvider.of<FormulariosBloc>(context).state as OnShowingFormularioDetail);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: AppDimens.getHeightByScreen(1, context),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: AppDimens.getHeightByScreen(0.82, context),
                child: Scrollbar(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  thumbVisibility: true,
                  thickness: 6,
                  radius: const Radius.circular(5.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                        FormfieldsFraction(
                          formFieldsAreEnabled: true,
                        ),  
                        const SizedBox(height: 3)
                      ]
                    )
                  )
                )
              ),
              BottomFormNavigation(
                formulario: widget.formulario,
                canPostpone: true,
                isVisitFormulario: widget.isVisitFormulario,
                canBack: onFormDetailState.canBack,
                canAdvance: onFormDetailState.canAdvance,
                nPages: onFormDetailState.nPages,
                currentPage: onFormDetailState.currentPage,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to create a variable form fields list (with textfields included). The textfield widgets are generating that the navigator push again the current screen.